# I have used Gson libary,but can see my output

Tags: android, gson

This is my Main Class.Can any one tell me why it s returning null in System.print().I have used `Gson` external libs.What i am doing wrong here.How can i display all contains

```
public class PostsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "PostsActivity";
    private List<Post> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);
        PostFetcher fetcher = new PostFetcher();
        fetcher.execute();
    }


    private void handlePostsList(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(Post post : PostsActivity.this.posts) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostsActivity.this, post.TITLE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void failedLoadingPosts() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(PostsActivity.this, "Failed to load Posts. Have a look at LogCat.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private class PostFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private static final String TAG = "PostFetcher";
        public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/android/DemoSchool/json/json_item.php";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //Create an HTTP client
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);

                //Perform the request and check the status code
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                    try {
                        //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
                        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                        Post po = gson.fromJson(reader, Post.class);
                        List<Post> posts = Arrays.asList(po);
                        System.out.println("ID:"+po);
                        content.close();

                        handlePostsList(posts);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                        failedLoadingPosts();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
                    failedLoadingPosts();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
                failedLoadingPosts();
            }
            return null;
        } 
    }
}
```

//Post.java

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public long ID;
    public String TITLE;
    public String AUTHOR;
    public String URL;
    @SerializedName("date")
    public Date dateCreated;
    public String body;

    public List<Tag> tags;

    public Post() {

    }
     public String toString() {
            return "Student [id=" + ID + ", title="
                    + TITLE + ", thumb_url=" + URL
                    + ", dt=" + AUTHOR + "]";
        } 
}
```

Comment: Sania, is it necessary to use GSON library? Should you use another one, so I can send you.

Comment: hey I am not telling that its unnecessary, I was just asking that, if its not necessary, then I have one method ready with me, so I can save time of her, just read things proper first!!1

Comment: No its not mandatory. But I thought its easiest way by using Gson lib

Comment: @Sania you can parse json directly, I think its easy way

Comment: u mean i have to create one more class for parsing rite??that way i know.

Comment: @sania can you send me your code, so let me check with Gson itself, because here not getting idea.

Comment: i have posted my both classes u just need to add Gson lib.i m just at d beginning of it

Comment: @Sania may I have your full project? so let me directly import it in my eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55692/discussion-between-pratik-and-sania).

Comment: your problem is solved....got response

Comment: Sania, are you there????

Comment: nothing happened @Sania

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to consider. First of all, your fields need have proper **@SerializedName("")** annotation. It indicates that the property name (like thumb_url, dt) does not match the field name in your JSON. If both names do match, there is no need for the annotation.

Secondly, you need to "parse" the response that you get from the server to JsonObject and then read the JsonElement.

Here's the code you need:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yy-d-M hh:mm");
//2014-06-14 02:39:24
//yy-d-M hh:mm
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject details = jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray array = details.getAsJsonArray("veg_food");
for ( JsonElement element : array ){
     Post post = gson.fromJson(element, Post.class);
     posts.add(post);
}
System.out.println("ID:"+ posts);
```

Also, make sure you change your `Post.java` class to this:

```
@SerializedName("id")
public long ID;
@SerializedName("title")
public String TITLE;
@SerializedName("thumb_url")
public String URL;
@SerializedName("dt")
public Date dateCreated;
```

Hope it helps.

**[EDIT]**

Output:

[image]

Comment: Y it s not displaying id..i changed it to String type @SerializedName("id") public String ID;

Comment: @Sania How are you displaying it? Try toasting `post.ID`